# piTFT 2.8 TouchScreen capacitive display TOUCHSCREEN feature does not work

Tags: pi-2, display, touchscreen, driver

On Raspberry PI 2 Model B, I am using 2.8 piTFT capacitive display. Plus, I used DIY installer helper on the adafruit website. Everything seem to have installed correctly and the screen comes up except TOUCHSCREEN feature is not working. I checked to make sure the drivers and libraries were installed. They are installed except for **stmpe_ts** and **touchscreen (/dev/input/touchscreen)**. They are missing. I don't know how or where to download this from. Does anyone have any idea. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution for this.

1. First download the latest and the greatest OS image file for your TYPE of display that specifically deals with your display. In my case, my display is capacitive touchscreen display. As it turns out, they have developed Raspbian specifically that works with my PiTFT display. So, I ended up downloading Raspbian Capacitive Display OS image off their website and unzipping the OS image file. Just simply Google it, if you are having problem finding it. It will take you right to the page.
2. Depending on your platform, you may need to download Win32DiskImager for Windows or follow these [steps](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/) if you are running anything else (linux or MacOs) to write your Raspbian image file to your SD card.
3. Finally, write to your SD card. Then, simply insert your SD card into your Raspberry PI and turn it on.